# Servlet response manipulate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, servlets

i want to load a html depending on Servlet return. How can i do it? Cause i understand that, if i do  `$("#risposta").html(data);`    set in my div the response of servlet but i can't operate with `data`.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>                                                                                    
<html lang="en">                                                                                   
<head>                                                                                             
    <title>Pagina di identificazione</title>                                                       
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>       
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">                            
</head>                                                                                            
<body>                                                                                             
<h2>Identificazione utente</h2>                                                                    
<form  method="post">                                                                              
    <p> Login: <input id="mail" type="text" name="login" value=""/> </p>                           
    <p>Password: <input id="pass" type="password" name="passwd"/></p>                              
    <p><input id="login" type="button" name="submit" value="login"/></p>                           
</form>                                                                                            
<div id="risposta" class="outputTextArea"></div>                                                   
<div id="insert" class="outputTextArea"></div>                                                     
<script type="text/javascript">                                                                    
        $(document).ready(function(){                                                              
        $("#login").click(function (){                                                             
                    const account = document.getElementById("mail").value;                         
                    const password = document.getElementById("pass").value;                        
                  $.post("validate-servlet",{mail: account,passwd: password},                      
                           function (data){                                                        
                               if(data ==="Studente") $("#insert").load("student.html");           
                                   else if(data ==="Docente")  $("#insert").load("insert.html");   
                               //alert(data);                                                      
                         });                                                                       
                 //$("#insert").load("insert.html");                                               
            });                                                                                    
        entById("response").value;                                                                 
                                                                                                   
                                                                                                   
        });                                                                                        
</script>                                                                                          
</body>                                                                                            
</html>
```

this is the servlet: getType return a string(Studente or Docente)

```
@WebServlet(name = "validateServlet", value = "/validate-servlet")
public class ValidateServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private DAO model = null;
    public void init(ServletConfig conf) throws ServletException {
        super.init(conf);
        ServletContext ctx = conf.getServletContext();
        String url = ctx.getInitParameter("DB-URL");
        String user = ctx.getInitParameter("user");
        String pwd = ctx.getInitParameter("pwd");
        model = new DAO(url,user,pwd);
    }
    public void destroy(){}
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            Persona user = DAO.Validate(request.getParameter("mail"),request.getParameter("passwd"));
            if(user!=null) {

                HttpSession s = request.getSession();
                s.setAttribute("Nome",user.getNome());
                s.setAttribute("Cognome",user.getCognome());
                s.setAttribute("Ruolo",user.getType());
                s.setAttribute("account",request.getParameter("mail"));
                s.setAttribute("psw",request.getParameter("passwd"));
                out.println(user.getType());
            }
            else out.println("NOT IN DB");
            out.flush();


    }
}
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the value of `data`?  (I don't mean copy the whole thing here, but is it html?  json?  a string?  Note that "studente" will not `==` "Studente" - so you need to be sure what value you *are* getting.

Comment: the value of data should be my "out.println(getType()) of my servlet. getType is correct beacuse if i do $("#risposta").html(data); write in my div Studente or Docente.

Comment: Add to `function (data) {` :  `console.log("[" + data + "]")` and look for any extra spaces etc

Comment: *should be* - doesn't matter what it *should* be, what *is* it... at the time it's used, not when it's sent.

Comment: i read https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. `data` is a PlainObject. When i try to `console.log("[" + data + "]")` it can't show anything on the log view.

Comment: so, my question is...How can i interact with this object? My servelt's response are catched by this object, but how? (this is my first time with jquery-servelt etc etc, i'm studying it)

Comment: It looks like your servlet is ok, but what's not clear is what jquery is seeing.   "can't show anything" - it *will* be either a console error or `[[Object object]]` or `[Studente]`.   If it's `[object]` then change to `console.log(data)` and expand the value in the browser console (F12).